# Change flare shape and size in flutter while rendering

Tags: flutter, size, width, rendering, flare

I have a simple flare object (a slate or blackboard) that I want to use in my app. The idea is to show some text in chalk on that blackboard. I am struggling to find the correct size of that blackboard. I would like the blackboard to fill out most of the screen. Therefore, I need to change the width or the height of the blackboard.

I haven't found a solution for that though. Is it possible to change the width of the blackboard by the factor 2 and the height by factor 1.5 in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

So, the easiest way for me to fill out the screen was to use the BoxFit.fill option. Still haven't figured out though how to individually change the height and width of a flare in flutter.

```
Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: FlareActor(
                'assets/Slate.flr',
                artboard: 'MainArtboard',
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                sizeFromArtboard: false,
```